# Issue with iostream.h on a C++ program

Tags: c++, compilation, iostream

I need to execute some examples founded in this page:
http://www.chuidiang.com/clinux/ipcs/colas.php

The code for one of them is this one:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct Mi_Tipo_Mensaje
{
long Id_Mensaje;
int Dato_Numerico;
char Mensaje[10];
};

main()
{
key_t Clave1;
int Id_Cola_Mensajes;
Mi_Tipo_Mensaje Un_Mensaje;

Clave1 = ftok ("/bin/ls", 33);
if (Clave1 == (key_t)-1)
{
    cout << "Error al obtener clave para cola mensajes" << endl;
    exit(-1);
}

Id_Cola_Mensajes = msgget (Clave1, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
if (Id_Cola_Mensajes == -1)
{
    cout << "Error al obtener identificador para cola mensajes" << endl;
    exit (-1);
}

Un_Mensaje.Id_Mensaje = 1;
Un_Mensaje.Dato_Numerico = 29;
strcpy (Un_Mensaje.Mensaje, "Hola");

msgsnd (Id_Cola_Mensajes, (struct msgbuf *)&Un_Mensaje, 
        sizeof(Un_Mensaje.Dato_Numerico)+sizeof(Un_Mensaje.Mensaje), 
        IPC_NOWAIT);

msgrcv (Id_Cola_Mensajes, (struct msgbuf *)&Un_Mensaje,
        sizeof(Un_Mensaje.Dato_Numerico) + sizeof(Un_Mensaje.Mensaje), 
        2, 0);

cout << "Recibido mensaje tipo 2" << endl;
cout << "Dato_Numerico = " << Un_Mensaje.Dato_Numerico << endl;
cout << "Mensaje = " << Un_Mensaje.Mensaje << endl;

msgctl (Id_Cola_Mensajes, IPC_RMID, (struct msqid_ds *)NULL);
    }
```

I'm trying to compile this as suggested in the page I'd mentioned ("make" or "g++ cola1.c -o cola1"), but I get this message:

```
fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
```

I know that this problem has been asked quite a lot, but I can't solve it yet, could you please give me some insights?
Thank you for your time and disposition,

Sebastián Pavez

Comment: Your first problem is whatever books or tutorials you use, they are **severely** outdated! There has been no `<iostream.h>` header file in C++ for many years. I recommend you look at a [good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).

Comment: try #include <iostream> rather then #include <iostream.h>

Comment: If you're using `iostream` then you don't have a `C` program, you have a `C++` program.

Comment: I wish I could downvote that *website*, it’s horrible.

Comment: `typedef struct ...` is also an anachronism in C++, though in C it still makes a difference. `main()` without return type, defaulting to int, is also something that even C doesn't do any more, I believe. Take a look at http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/, which should give you a starter.

Answer (score 3):

You have a bunch of problems in your code.

1. `iostream.h` is not part of the C++ standard and you should instead import `iostream`.
2. You never add the `std` namespace to  the appropriate functions. You can simply add the line `using namespace std;` at the beginning of your program (although this is discouraged, look at your favorite reference what functions *live*  in the std namespace and prepend them with `std::`).
3. Plain `main()` is wrong, it has to return an `int`. Change it to `int main()` and add at the end of the `main` function the line `return 0`. As suggested by *Joachim Pileborg* in the comments you can omit the return statement because the compiler will add it if it's missing.
4. You use functions that are declared in the headerfiles `cstring` (`strcpy`) and `cstdlib` (`exit`), so include them:

   ```
   #include <cstring>
   #include <cstdlib>
   ```
5. The `typedef` in the line `typedef struct Mi_Tipo_Mensaje` is redundant and not necessary. Remove it.

BTW: A lot of things in your code suggest that you are writing a C++ program instead of a C one.

Comment: Using `using namespace std;` is actually discouraged. It's okay to import certain classes or objects (most usually `std::cout`/std::cin`) from `std`, but not the complete namespace. Also, `return 0;` isn't needed at the end of the `main` function, if it's missing the compiler adds it for you.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are right, and writing *it is not recommended* is to weak. *Discouraged* is the better word :). Just wanted to make my job easy that OP can compile and run his code with as little changes as necessary. Regarding the optional `return`. I thought it's only true for C but you are right.

Answer (score 0):

C++ standard header filenames don't end in `.h`.  Just use `#include <iostream>`.